# How to make a query with whereIn with json values sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to make a query in sqlalchemy with a json, but this query should be of the type whereIn where the values ​​are in the values ​​I give them

For examples I give

```
class Product(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Product, self).__init__()
        self.product = self.Base.classes.products
        self.session = Session(self.engine)

    def get_products(self, data):
        print(data)
        query = self.session.query(self.product)

        product = query.filter(self.product.attributes.like(data['attributes']))

        print(product.get())
```

In my database these attributes are like this

```
"[{\"Brand\":\"Kanu\"},{\"Shade\":\"Red, Yellow\"},{\"Material\":\"Artificial Leather\"}]"
```

How could I proceed?
Can sql alchemy make this difference or should I do the query manually?

What error I got

```
LINE 3: WHERE products.attributes LIKE '["{''Ideal For'': ''Women''}...
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish, than you can use the `.in_` method from SQLAlchemy (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_)

For example: 

`product.attributes.in_([...])`